# Create a request when the program starts, and read the username and password at runtime. ( Tkinter)

Tags: python, webdav, nextcloud

My project is to develop a Python application that allows users to encrypt their client-side data and store it securely on my university's nextcloud collaboration system via WebDAV.
The access data (username / password) should not be saved as is in the Python file, it is too insecure, when I enter it clearly in the program, the file is encrypted and then sent in the cloud from my GUI successfully.
but when I tried to create a query on program start and read input data to access the cloud at runtime. but it doesn't work the file can't send

I tried this one :

```
username = simpledialog.askstring("Authentifizierung", "Benutzername:", parent=window)


password = simpledialog.askstring("Authentifizierung", "Passwort:", parent=window, show='*')


options = {
    'webdav_hostname': f'https://ccs.jade-hs.de/remote.php/dav/files/{username}/',
    'webdav_login': username,
    'webdav_password': password
}
```

I had the following problem: The encryption of my is done correctly, but it can not be sent to the nextcloud, I still have this error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\DELL\Downloads\IWA_end (1).py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\_init.py", line 1948, in _call
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Downloads\IWA_end (1).py", line 79, in select_file
    upload_file(encrypted_file_path)
  File "c:\Users\DELL\Downloads\IWA_end (1).py", line 116, in upload_file
    client.upload_sync(remote_path=filename, local_path=file_path)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdav3\client.py", line 663, in upload_sync
    self.upload(local_path=local_path, remote_path=remote_path, progress=progress, progress_args=progress_args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdav3\client.py", line 562, in upload
    self.upload_file(local_path=local_path, remote_path=remote_path, progress_args=progress_args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdav3\client.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    res = fn(self, *args, **kw)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdav3\client.py", line 626, in upload_file
    raise RemoteParentNotFound(urn.path())
webdav3.exceptions.RemoteParentNotFound: Remote parent for: /sarachi.txt.encrypted not found
```

Any thoughts!